# Symfony 1.4 not loading sfTestFunctional failing with class not found

Tags: php, symfony-1.4, functional-testing

I've done my functional tests and now I want to run them. However, every time I run them I get sfTestFunctional class not found.

As far as I can tell the functional.php bootstrap is not autoloading the classes from the framework. Any reason why this could be?

This is my functional bootstrap

```
// guess current application
if (!isset($app))
{
  $traces = debug_backtrace();
  $caller = $traces[0];

  $dirPieces = explode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, dirname($caller['file']));
  $app = array_pop($dirPieces);
}

require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/../../config/ProjectConfiguration.class.php';
$configuration = ProjectConfiguration::getApplicationConfiguration($app, 'test', isset($debug) ? $debug : true);

sfContext::createInstance($configuration);


// remove all cache
sfToolkit::clearDirectory(sfConfig::get('sf_app_cache_dir'));

$doctrine = new sfDoctrineDropDbTask($configuration->getEventDispatcher(), new sfAnsiColorFormatter());
$doctrine->run(array(), array("--no-confirmation","--env=test"));

$doctrine = new sfDoctrineBuildDbTask($configuration->getEventDispatcher(), new sfAnsiColorFormatter());
$doctrine->run(array(), array("--env=test"));

$doctrine = new sfDoctrineInsertSqlTask($configuration->getEventDispatcher(), new sfAnsiColorFormatter());
$doctrine->run(array(), array("--env=test"));
```

This is what is in my the functional tests

```
include(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../bootstrap/functional.php');

$browser = sfTestFunctional(new sfBrowser());
Doctrine_Core::loadData(sfConfig::get('sf_test_dir').'/fixtures/fixtures_initial.yml');
```

Comment: Does the `require_once` to `ProjectConfiguration` is right? And what is inside `$app` ?

Comment: I think $app is the test:functional [application] - that was what was already in the functional.php bootstrap. The require_once was also in the bootstrap. The require_once command matches the unit.php bootstrap which works.

Comment: You're right that's the default `test/bootstrap/functional.php` :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok. So after banging my head against the wall, I found a solution.

For some reason within the test environment custom filters are not autoloaded. The solution is to add require_once for all the custom filters to the ProjectConfiguration file. Here is the example of what I did:

```
if(sfConfig::get('sf_environment') == 'test' && sfConfig::get('sf_app') == 'frontend')
{
    require_once sfConfig::get('sf_app_lib_dir').'/myFilter.class.php';
    require_once sfConfig::get('sf_app_lib_dir').'/myotherFilter.class.php';
    require_once sfConfig::get('sf_app_lib_dir').'/lovefiltersFilter.php';
    require_once sfConfig::get('sf_app_lib_dir').'/eventsManagement.class.php';

    require_once sfConfig::get('sf_test_dir').'/ProdPadTestFunctional.class.php';
}
```

I also had to add my custom testFuntional class as well. This might be more elegantly done using the autoload.yml file.

Comment: This might be related to this [ticket](http://trac.symfony-project.org/ticket/4524).

Comment: Yes I think it is. Surprised it hasn't been fixed in 1.4.18, I guess it isn't a priority.

Answer (score 0):

I spot the problem:

```
$browser = sfTestFunctional(new sfBrowser());
```

You should write:

```
$browser = new sfTestFunctional(new sfBrowser());
```

Comment: Hmmmm...I'm confusing myself pretty sure that was correct as it failed on other functional tests with new sfTestFunctional(). Anyway now it is producing another class not found error this time for one of my filters I wrote.  Seems to be something related to non framework code and classes.